# Use nativeHandle in Linux

Tags: firefox-addon, jsctypes

I frequently use `nativeHandle` with js-ctypes in Windows.

I would like to now use it in Linux. This code below focuses the window but it then crashes. You can see the window get focused. It doesn't crash when I don't use nativeHandle.

How can I avoid the crash? There is nothing wrong with the code except this:

`var cHwnd = ctypes.voidptr_t(ctypes.UInt64(tBaseWin.nativeHandle));`

You can copy paste this code to scratchpad and run, you will see the window focus then Firefox will crash.

Code is pasted below

```
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm')

var nixtypesInit = function() {
    // BASIC TYPES (ones that arent equal to something predefined by me)
    this.ATOM = ctypes.unsigned_long;
    this.BOOL = ctypes.int;
    this.CHAR = ctypes.char;
    this.DATA = ctypes.voidptr_t;
    this.DISPLAY = new ctypes.StructType('Display');
    this.INT = ctypes.int;
    this.LONG = ctypes.long;
    this.STATUS = ctypes.int;
    this.UNSIGNED_CHAR = ctypes.unsigned_char;
    this.UNSIGNED_LONG = ctypes.unsigned_long;
    this.WINDOW = ctypes.unsigned_long;

    // ADVANCED TYPES (ones that are equal to something predefined by me)
    /* http://www.man-online.org/page/3-XClientMessageEvent/
     * typedef struct {
     *   int            type;       // ClientMessage
     *   unsigned long  serial;     // # of last request processed by server
     *   Bool           send_event; // true if this came from a SendEvent request
     *   Display        *display;   // Display the event was read from
     *   Window         window;
     *   Atom           message_type;
     *   int            format;
     *   union {
     *     char         b[20];
     *     short        s[10];
     *     long         l[5];
     *   } data;
     * } XClientMessageEvent; 
     */
     this.XCLIENTMESSAGEEVENT = new ctypes.StructType('XClientMessageEvent', [
        { 'type': ctypes.int },             // ClientMessage
        { 'serial': ctypes.unsigned_long }, // # of last request processed by server
        { 'send_event': this.BOOL },        // true if this came from a SendEvent request
        { 'display': this.DISPLAY.ptr },    // Display the event was read from
        { 'window': this.WINDOW },
        { 'message_type': this.ATOM },
        { 'format': ctypes.int },
        { 'l0': ctypes.long },
        { 'l1': ctypes.long },
        { 'l2': ctypes.long },
        { 'l3': ctypes.long },
        { 'l4': ctypes.long }
    ]);

    // CONSTANTS
    this.BADGC = 13;
    this.NONE = 0;
    this.NULL = ctypes.cast(ctypes.uint64_t(0x0), ctypes.voidptr_t);
}
var ostypes = new nixtypesInit();
console.log('ostypes.NULL:', ostypes.NULL, uneval(ostypes.NULL))
var lib = {};
function _lib(path) {
    //ensures path is in lib, if its in lib then its open, if its not then it adds it to lib and opens it. returns lib
    //path is path to open library
    //returns lib so can use straight away

    if (!(path in lib)) {
        //need to open the library
        //default it opens the path, but some things are special like libc in mac is different then linux or like x11 needs to be located based on linux version
        switch (path) {
            case 'x11':
                try {
                    lib[path] = ctypes.open('libX11.so.6');
                } catch (e) {
                    try {
                        var libName = ctypes.libraryName('X11');
                    } catch (e) {
                        console.error('Integration Level 1: Could not get libX11 name; not activating', 'e:' + e);
                        throw new Error('Integration Level 1: Could not get libX11 name; not activating, e:' + e);
                    }

                    try {
                        lib[path] = ctypes.open(libName);
                    } catch (e) {
                        console.error('Integration Level 2: Could not get libX11 name; not activating', 'e:' + e);
                        throw new Error('Integration Level 2: Could not get libX11 name; not activating, e:' + e);
                    }
                }
                break;
            default:
                try {
                    lib[path] = ctypes.open(path);
                } catch (e) {
                    console.error('Integration Level 1: Could not get open path:', path, 'e:' + e);
                    throw new Error('Integration Level 1: Could not get open path:"' + path + '" e: "' + e + '"');
                }
        }
    }
    return lib[path];
}

// declares in this worker, i set them all = to null for the scratchpad because i may declare it wrong and it wont re-declare unless if it first the var is !
var dec = {};
function _dec(declaration) { // it means ensureDeclared and return declare. if its not declared it declares it. else it returns the previously declared.
    if (!(declaration in dec)) {
        dec[declaration] = preDec[declaration](); //if declaration is not in preDec then dev messed up
    }
    return dec[declaration];
}

var preDec = { //stands for pre-declare (so its just lazy stuff) //this must be pre-populated by dev // do it alphabateized by key so its ez to look through
    DefaultRootWindow: function() {
        // MACRO
        /* http://www.xfree86.org/4.4.0/DefaultRootWindow.3.html
         * Window DefaultRootWindow(
         *   Display    *display
         * );
         */
        return _lib('x11').declare('XDefaultRootWindow', ctypes.default_abi,
            ostypes.WINDOW,     // return
            ostypes.DISPLAY.ptr // *display
        );
    },
    XCloseDisplay: function() {
        /* http://www.xfree86.org/4.4.0/XCloseDisplay.3.html
         * int XCloseDisplay(
         *   Display    *display
         * );
         */
        return _lib('x11').declare('XCloseDisplay', ctypes.default_abi,
            ostypes.INT,        // return
            ostypes.DISPLAY.ptr // *display
        );
    },
    XFlush: function() {
        /* http://www.xfree86.org/4.4.0/XFlush.3.html
         * int XFlush(
         *   Display    *display
         * );
         */
        return _lib('x11').declare('XFlush', ctypes.default_abi,
            ostypes.INT,        // return
            ostypes.DISPLAY.ptr // *display
        );
    },
    XFree: function() {
        /* http://www.xfree86.org/4.4.0/XFree.3.html
         * int XFree(
         *   void   *data
         * );
         */
        return _lib('x11').declare('XFree', ctypes.default_abi,
            ostypes.INT,    // return
            ostypes.DATA    // *data
        );
    },
    XInternAtom: function() {
        /* http://www.xfree86.org/4.4.0/XInternAtom.3.html
         * Atom XInternAtom(
         *   Display    *display,
         *   char       *atom_name,
         *   Bool       only_if_exists
         * );
         */
         return _lib('x11').declare('XInternAtom', ctypes.default_abi,
            ostypes.ATOM,           // return
            ostypes.DISPLAY.ptr,    // *display
            ostypes.CHAR.ptr,       // *atom_name
            ostypes.BOOL            // only_if_exists
        );
    },
    XMapRaised: function() {
        /* http://www.xfree86.org/4.4.0/XMapRaised.3.html
         * int XMapRaised(
         *   Display *display
         *   Window w
         * );
         */
        return _lib('x11').declare('XMapRaised', ctypes.default_abi,
            ostypes.INT,            // return
            ostypes.DISPLAY.ptr,    // *display
            ostypes.WINDOW          // w
        );
    },
    XOpenDisplay: function() {
        /* http://www.xfree86.org/4.4.0/XOpenDisplay.3.html
         * Display *XOpenDisplay(
         *   char   *display_name
         * );
         */
        return _lib('x11').declare('XOpenDisplay', ctypes.default_abi,
            ostypes.DISPLAY.ptr,    // return
            ostypes.CHAR.ptr        // *display_name
        ); 
    },
    XSendEvent: function() {
        /* http://www.xfree86.org/4.4.0/XSendEvent.3.html
         * Status XSendEvent(
         *   Display *display,
         *   Window w,
         *   Bool propagate,
         *   long event_mask,
         *   XEvent *event_send
         * ); 
         */
        return _lib('x11').declare('XSendEvent', ctypes.default_abi,
            ostypes.STATUS,                 // return
            ostypes.DISPLAY.ptr,            // *display
            ostypes.WINDOW,                 // w
            ostypes.BOOL,                   // propagate
            ostypes.LONG,                   // event_mask
            ostypes.XCLIENTMESSAGEEVENT.ptr // event_sent*
        ); 
    }
}

function OpenNewXDisplay() {
    var nullChar = ctypes.cast(ostypes.NULL, ostypes.CHAR.ptr);
    var rez_XOpenDisplay = _dec('XOpenDisplay')(nullChar);
    if (rez_XOpenDisplay.isNull()) {
        throw new Error('XOpenDisplay failed to open display');
    }
    return rez_XOpenDisplay;
}

var GetXDisplayConst = undefined; //ostypes.DISPLAY // runtime defined constants
function GetXDisplay() {
    if (!GetXDisplayConst) {
        GetXDisplayConst = OpenNewXDisplay();
    }
    return GetXDisplayConst;
}

function shutdown() {
    if (GetXDisplay() && GetXDisplay().isNull && !GetXDisplay().isNull()) {
        var rez_XCloseDisplay = _dec('XCloseDisplay')(GetXDisplay());
        if (rez_XCloseDisplay != 0) {
            throw new Error('XCloseDisplay failed with error code: ' + rez_XCloseDisplay);
        }
    }

    for (var l in lib) {
        lib[l].close();
    }
}

var GetAtomCache = {};
function GetAtom(name) {
    // name is ostypes.CHAR.ptr
    // returns ostypes.ATOM
    if (!(name in GetAtomCache)) {      
        var atom = _dec('XInternAtom')(GetXDisplay(), name, 0); //passing 3rd arg of false, means even if atom doesnt exist it returns a created atom, this can be used with GetProperty to see if its supported etc, this is how Chromium does it
        if (atom == ostypes.NONE) { //will never equal ostypes.NONE because i pass 3rd arg of `false` to XInternAtom
            console.warn('No atom with name:', name, 'return val of atom:', atom, uneval(atom), atom.toString());
            throw new Error('No atom with name "' + name + '"), return val of atom:"' +  atom + '" toString:"' + atom.toString() + '"');
        }
        GetAtomCache[name] = atom;
    }
    return GetAtomCache[name];
}

function main() {
    var tWin = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser');
    if (!tWin) {
        throw new Error('getMostRecentWindow failed to find a window');
    }
    var tBaseWin = tWin.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor).getInterface(Ci.nsIWebNavigation).QueryInterface(Ci.nsIDocShellTreeItem).treeOwner.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor).getInterface(Ci.nsIBaseWindow);
    var cHwnd = ostypes.WINDOW(tBaseWin.nativeHandle);
    console.info('debug-msg :: cHwnd : ', cHwnd, uneval(cHwnd), cHwnd.toString());


    var rootWin = _dec('DefaultRootWindow')(GetXDisplay());
    console.info('debug-msg :: rootWin:', rootWin, uneval(rootWin), rootWin.toString());

    var event = new ostypes.XCLIENTMESSAGEEVENT();
    event.type = 33;
    event.serial = 0;
    event.send_event = 1;
    event.message_type = GetAtom('_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW'); //_dec('XInternAtom')(GetXDisplay(), '_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW', 0);
    event.display = GetXDisplay();
    event.window = cHwnd;
    event.format = 32;
    event.l0 = 2;
    var mask = 1 << 20 /* SubstructureRedirectMask */ | 1 << 19 /* SubstructureNotifyMask */ ;
    var rez_XSendEvent = _dec('XSendEvent')(GetXDisplay(), rootWin, 0, mask, event.address());
    console.info('debug-msg :: rez_XSendEvent:', rez_XSendEvent, uneval(rez_XSendEvent), rez_XSendEvent.toString());
    if (rez_XSendEvent) {
        var rez_XMapRaised = _dec('XMapRaised')(GetXDisplay(), cHwnd);
        console.info('debug-msg :: rez_XMapRaised:', rez_XMapRaised, uneval(rez_XMapRaised), rez_XMapRaised.toString());
        var rez_XFlush = _dec('XFlush')(GetXDisplay());
        console.info('debug-msg :: rez_XFlush:', rez_XFlush, uneval(rez_XFlush), rez_XFlush.toString());
        console.log('Activated successfully');
        return true;
    } else {
        console.warn('An error occurred activating the window');
        return false;
    }
}

try {
    main();
} catch(ex) {
    console.error(ex);
} finally {
    shutdown();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found and MDN updated, done awhile ago but I thought would post solution here too.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Finding_Window_Handles#Unix

Answer (score 1):

One source of trouble might be the line `event.l0 = 2`. That defines the source of the event as a Pager, which is not true. I would recommend to zero all five `l` members.

Comment: Thanks paa for that, the thing is though, the focus window thing works fine, I just don't know how to take a nativeHandle and feed it. This guy does some weird stuff I cant figure out: https://github.com/v-fox/live_opensuse_hsf/blob/61ecaa23b0885e8c28e3a56046faa114a51424f1/source/root/home/hacker/.thunderbird/mcos93yg.hacker/extensions/%7B9533f794-00b4-4354-aa15-c2bbda6989f8%7D/modules/linux/FiretrayWindow.jsm#L169 he did : `let gdkw = new gdk.GdkWindow.ptr(ctypes.UInt64(nativeHandle)); // a new pointer to the GdkWindow`

Comment: Using those values for client send event didnt crash when i get window by means other than nativeHandle, see here I did it with XQueryTree, you just have to supply it a pid on line 340: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/60aab0a96f060240614f#file-_ff-addon-snippet-x11_focusmostrecentwindowofpid-js-L340 and can copy paste that code.

Comment: @Noitidart I can't execute your code, I get an error about `XInternAtom` not being defined

Comment: Ah ok ill give some simpler code one sec plz. I'll use function http://linux.die.net/man/3/xgetwmname XGetWMName its very simple function.

Comment: Hey paa I made a very basic example, this one you can't see the effects taking place though before the crash. It just tries to get the window name of the window. Very basic, things that are not needed are not included. It woulbe so awesome if you could please help me to get `nativeHandle` working on x11 :D https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/04a10ad30cb8e54bb8f9 you can see the readme in the comments area, the line that crashes is feeding the `cHwnd` to te `XGetWMName` function. Copy pastable but note it crashes.

Comment: i also fixed the code in the topicpost above, its copy pastable to scratchpad. forgive the bad code thatnks very much for posting trying to help despite the poor quality question!!